# How to install php_dba.dll for PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, windows

i try to install PrivMX WebMail but seems like one error still problem here,

php-dba     PROBLEM

i try to find php_dba.dll on php.ini but it seems there is nothing there
im trying to find it on google but still fail

currently im using  PHP  version: 5.6.12 witn wampwebserver on windowns server

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no php_dba.dll distributed officially until PHP 7.2. Even if you compile it yourself for lower, you might need to get drivers you need manually. Particularly for Oracle. Otherwise you should be fine just upgrading to 7.2 as it also suports LMDB.

Thanks.